# In CQ How to disable any field in child page properties dialog?

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I have added a new selection type field "Theme" in page properties>Basic. 
Now if I add a new page using the same template in WCM, there also I 
am getting the option "Theme", which is quite obvious. 
Is there any way by which I can hide the field in child page?

P.S this is happening because I am using the same template for the child page.

Comment: So you want a property editable only on the parent page and not on any child pages. And you want the property to inherit to the child pages?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the same template and have the page property dialogs be different.

What you can do is overload the dialog

- create a new template and corresponding resourceType component that
  inherit from your current.
- copy the dialog, or tab that you want to be different from the lowest parent of the           component. Make sure the dialog is the only node under the component.
- Make the changes you want to the dialog.

You would then have to include code in the page jsp to get the parent page property something like:

```
// if the parent page is always a certain level below the root you can use
// currentPage.getAbsoluteParent(3); to get the third page down from the top
// of the current path tree.
Page parentPage = currentPage.getParent();

ValueMap parentPageProperties;

if (parentPage != null) {
    parentPageProperties = parentPage.getProperties();
}

// This tries to get the property 'theme' from the current page. If that fails
// then it tries to get the property from the parent page. If that fails it 
// defaults to blank.
theme = properties.get("theme", parentPageProperties.get("theme", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would also be to create a second set of template / page component. Let's assume you've got template A, that uses page component B as resource type:

- Create template X and play with allowedParents allowedChildren and allowedPaths properties so that the two are exclusive (actual solution depends on your content architecture)
- Give X same title as A
- Create page component Y that extends B, and defines it's own dialog
- Make Y's dialog re-use any tabs from B using xtype=cqinclude (see foundation page's dialog for reference)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your valuable replies. I implemented it in some other way.

write a listener parallel to the property and hide the field by using findByType("selection")[i].hide();